# why the menu icon has been pushed to left when being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a website with a fixed navbar with jQuery sliding animation for the menu.I don't know why the "menu_icon" being pushed to the left everytime the menu slide down and it goes back to where is was after the menu slide up. Is there some problems with the structure of my HTML code or I made mistakes somewhere with my CSS. I am still learning CSS, so my code is bit of messy. But please let me know how to fix it.
you can find our code on [codepen.](https://codepen.io/kingsfull123/pen/wyYPOg?editors=1100)

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    Industries
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="Menu">Menu</span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Elements</li>
    <li>Generics</li>
  </ul>
</header>
<section id="heading">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Industries</h1>
    <p>A responsive business oriented template with a video background designed by TEMPLATED and released under the Creative Commons License.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="one">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3>SEM TURPIS AMET SEMPER</h3>
    <p>In arcu accumsan arcu adipiscing accumsan orci ac. Felis id enim aliquet. Accumsan ac integer lobortis commodo ornare aliquet accumsan erat tempus amet porttitor.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="six_blocks">
    <div id="block">
      <span></span>
      <h5>FEUGIAT CONSEQUAT</h5>
      <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis ipsum. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block">
      <span></span>
      <h5>ANTE SEM INTEGER</h5>
      <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis ipsum. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block">
      <span></span>
      <h5>IPSUM CONSEQUAT</h5>
      <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis ipsum. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block">
      <span></span>
      <h5>INTERDUM GRAVIDA</h5>
      <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis ipsum. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block">
      <span></span>
      <h5>FAUCIBUS CONSEQUAT</h5>
      <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis ipsum. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block">
      <span></span>
      <h5>ACCUMSAN VIVERRA</h5>
      <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis ipsum. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="two">
  <div id="inner">
    <h3>CURABITUR ULLAMCORPER ULTRICIES</h3>
    <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus ornare mi ut ante amet placerat aliquet. Volutpat eu sed ante lacinia sapien lorem accumsan varius montes viverra nibh in adipiscing. Lorem
      ipsum dolor vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus vestibulum. Blandit adipiscing eu felis iaculis volutpat ac adipiscing sed feugiat eu faucibus. Integer ac sed amet praesent. Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac gravida.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: The issue is not reproducible from your code

Answer (score 0):

Thats happening because the element #sliding is static\relative, and it expand his parent width and because your direction is ltr the button stay on left corner of his container #menu.

You can solve this by adding different text-align to #menu element and the right text-align you need to the #sliding or just make #sliding be absolute\fixed element.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sliding div is relative/static position. When jquery sliding function is perform then on slideup div became `display:none;` but when you click again then it will take full width (15em). that is the problem  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sunildeveloper07/pen/KQGRKZ)

```
#menu_icon {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Add this code in your code. It will solve your problem. It make anchor div to full width and text align to right side

Comment: Welcome can you Please accept my answer as working ans?